# Is there a propagation delay between SQLite connections for committed data?

Tags: c++, macos, sqlite

We have a C++ application on OSX (10.10.4) running natively on a MacBook Pro (no VM), using SQLite 3.7.7.1 (old, I realize), and I'm seeing the following behavior:

1. Thread 1 of app has connection to file1.db (on an Journaled HFS+ partition), creates a savepoint, inserts rows into table1, then releases savepoint.
2. Thread 2 of same app has connection to file2.db, and has previously attached file1.db in the same connection.  It now tries to insert into file2.table2 by selecting from file1.table1.

If 1 & 2 occur close together (within 1 second), we are seeing that the row inserted in step 1 is not inserted into table2.  But if we wait 1 second between steps 1 & 2, we always see the row inserted.  Step 2 is definitely occurring after Step 1 commits, as we are logging the statements and can observe it.

We are running in the default journal_mode (delete).

Is there some kind of propagation delay between connections shared by the same application when in journal_mode=delete?  The rules governing isolation levels (https://www.sqlite.org/isolation.html) don't expressly forbid it.

Comment: File system? Virtual machine? And your understanding of WAL mode is wrong.

Comment: I've updated my question to include the extra environment information (OSX 10.10.4, Journaled HFS+, no VM), and removed my comment on WAL, as I had only read about it a few minutes before posting the question and was only speculating.

Comment: In theory, this cannot happen. Which PRAGMA configuration options are you using?

Comment: The sqlite library was compiled with no pragma options, and at runtime we're only specifying PRAGMA foreign_keys=ON

Comment: I suspect that the fact that file1.db is attached to connection 2 means that connection 2 is only seeing changes that have reached the disk, despite both connections being inside the same executable.  I'll see if I can create a test case that recreates the issue and submit it here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem Solved:

The source of this behavior was due to a misunderstanding on our part regarding how savepoints work. Specifically, rollback back a savepoint does not remove the savepoint, so subsequent operations on a connection after a "ROLLBACK TO" command are still within the original savepoint's transaction.

In our case, there was a savepoint prior to the savepoint described in step 1 which had rolled back, such that Thread 1's work within its released savepoint was still not visible to other connections. Subsequent operations within thread 1 using a savepoint with the same name as the previously rolled-back savepoint were RELEASED, which finally committed the data from Thread 1, which is why we saw the data appear later on in Thread 2's connection.

Since we're using a simple Savepoint class as a stack-created protection object, which keeps track of how many levels we're nested when creating savepoints (which is how the savepoint names get reused), the solution was simply to make sure that the outermost savepoint created (i.e., the one created when there are no other savepoints currently active on that connection) uses "BEGIN TRANSACTION"/"COMMIT"/"ROLLBACK" and all savepoints created within that one use "SAVEPOINT SP_1", "SAVEPOINT_SP2", etc.